# How to simplify my Python program?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying this Compound Interest problem I found on the internet:

A=P(1+r) n, where P is the amount invested, r is the annual percentage rate (as a decimal 5.0%=0.050) and n is the number of years of the investment.

3 lists representing investments, rates, and terms

```
investment = [10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 1.00]
rate = [5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 50.00] 
term = [20, 40, 20, 40, 40]
```

I made my program like this but I feel instead of writing everything out like I did, I could use something called a loop, but I'm not sure how I can use a for loop properly cuz everytime I do, I mess it up:

```
rateindecimal = [int(rate[0])/100.0, int(rate[1])/100.0, int(rate[2])/100.0), int(rate[3])/100.0, int(rate[4])/100.0]
```

I converted the percent rate into a decimal, but how can I use a loop instead to run through the rate list and convert it easily?

Then I did this. I feel it's too repetitive and once again, I feel that I need a loop but I'm not very good in using one...

```
A1 = int(Investment[0]) * (1 + ratedecimal[0])**int(term[0])
A2 = int(Investment[1]) * (1 + ratedecimal[1])**int*term[1])
```

etc...

```
print "$" + str(round(A1, 2))
print "$" + str(round(A2, 2))
```

etc with that as well.

I'm sorry if this is really lengthy. I just want to know how to loop through it all so I don't have to be so repetitive.

Thanks!

Comment: You really do need to learn some basics of programming in Python.  There is a tutorial you can use called "Learn Python the Hard Way".  It would be best to start at the beginning, but if you want, you can skip ahead to the chapter on loops.  You can use this tutorial for free; or buy some sort of video if you prefer.  http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Answer (score 5):

Use `zip()` to zip them together and then `.format()` the output:

```
for investment, rate, term in zip(investments, rates, terms):
    A = investment * (1 - rate / 100) ** term

    print '${0:.02f}'.format(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Alist = [int(Investment[i]) * (1 + ratedecimal[i])*int(term[i]) for i in range(0,len(investment)]
```

This will give a list containing your intended A1,A2,A3..etc

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following basic approach, which is one of the simplest ways to loop in python:

```
A = list()
# The following will execute the body of the loop for all numbers from 0 to the number
# of items in investment - 1. So in your case i = 0 to 4
for i in range(len(investment)):
   rateindecimal = int(rate[i])/100
   A.append(int(investment[i]) * (1 + ratedecimal)**int(term[i]))
   print "$", str(round(A,2))
```

I'm not sure about the rounding though, because I think that because you use int() so often,
there will not be a floating point number to round... Maybe you should try float() instead.

For more info on for-loops in python, check out [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some loops that do what you need I think.

```
investment = [10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 1.00]
rate = [5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 50.00] 
term = [20, 40, 20, 40, 40]

# this is how I would use a loop in your first problem
rateindecimal = list()
for i in range(0, len(rate)):
    rateindecimal.append(int(rate[i])/100.0)

# this is how i'd solve your second problem
a = list()
for i in range(0, len(investment)):
    a.append(int(investment[i]) * (1 + rateindecimal[i])**int(term[i]))

# then a loop for the printing
for result in a:
    # print "${0}".format(str(round(result, 2)))
    print '$%.3f' % round(result, 2)
```

Comment: Might want to change your indices from 0 to i than, for your second loop ;)

Comment: @KevinMullin Thank you so much for your help! Is there any way, though, that I can round A to the hundredths place?  I tried, but it's not working...

Comment: @user2006236 I adjusted my answer to output the float value differently. You can adjust it yourself by changing the number within this string, which specifies how many decimal places to show. '%.3f'

Answer (score 0):

For a basic problem like this, I think it is best to keep the code simple.  Simple code is easy to read and understand, and easy to write.

Here is a solution that uses three nested `for` loops:

```
lst_investment_amt = [10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 1.00]
lst_rate = [5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 50.00]
lst_term = [20, 40, 20, 40, 40]


for amt in lst_investment_amt:
    for rate in lst_rate:
        for term in lst_term:
            r = 1.0 + (rate / 100.0)
            final = amt * r**term
            print("amt: $%6d\trate: %2.1f\tterm: %2d\tfinal: %15.2f" %
                (int(amt), rate, term, final))
    print('') # insert blank line to set off previous amount from next one
```

Notice that because we have three actual nested loops, I was able to add a `print('')` statement to print a blank line, to separate each amount from each next amount.

Python has some really slick features: list comprehensions, generator expressions, `zip()`.  But for a problem this simple, I really think the above code is the way to go.

Note how I used the `%` format codes here.  When you do a code like `%6.2f` this means "print a float value, where the total value will be 6 characters long, and there will be two digits after the decimal point".  The decimal point counts as a character, so this will be a number in the format of `123.45`, with three digits before the decimal and two after.  If the number is too big (for example, `100000.55`) then it will be allowed to expand out of the 6 character limit, but if it is too small (for example, `1.0`) it will be padded out with spaces.

Note also my use of `\t` to put tab characters in the printed output, to separate values and make things line up vertically.

Code like this, with nested loops, and print statements with format codes, can be used in the C language, C++, and various other languages as well as Python.